# How do you add text to JTextArea? (console simulation)

Tags: java, swing, console, jtextarea

How does one add text/commands (like in console) into JTextArea?

Or, more specifically, how can I add a JTextArea as console in my FTP program and add commands like C:\tmp\ -list with non-editable text added earlier?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a possibility. You can use the [JTextArea.append(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method for this:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.append("Your new String");
```

From JavaDoc:

> Appends the given text to the end of the document.

Take care that you have to add line breaks by yourself like

```
textArea.append("Your new String\n");
```

if you want to add a new line to the end.

---

If you want to have a real selfmade console, look for example at [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) or [JLine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/).

Comment: Heh, not exacly what I mean. I want to have JTextArea as console in my FTP program and possibility of adding commands like ie. C:\tmp\ -list with non-editable text added earlier.

Comment: I've added two examples for a selfmade console. This could be an option for what you really want to do. It's probably not that easy to implement it by yourself...

Comment: JLine looks good. Thanks for links.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very incomplete answer but it is a start. This code is for a Test.java which extends javax.swing.JFrame. It builds a simple GUI, creates a new PrintStream and OutputStream (which overrides write(int b) to append a character to the JTextArea), uses System.setOut(PrintStream), then System.out.println(String) to test it out.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author caucow
 */
public class Test extends JFrame {

    PrintStream printOut;
    OutputStream out;
    JPanel container;
    JTextArea example;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Test() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create the JTextArea with some default text.
        example = new JTextArea("//There is some text here\n");

        example.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        add(example);

        // Create the OutputStream which will be written to when using System.out
        out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            // Override the write(int) method to append the character to the JTextArea
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                example.append("" + (char) b);
            }
        };

        // Create the PrintStream that System.out will be set to.
        // Make sure autoflush is true.
        printOut = new PrintStream(out, true);

        // Set the system output to the PrintStream
        System.setOut(printOut);

        // Test it out
        System.out.println("\nTest Output");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("More testing.");
        System.out.println("Line 4");
        System.out.println("Bob says hi.");
    }
}
```

For full console functionality, you could override the JTextAreas text processing method, and add key/mouse listeners to setEnabled(boolean) whenever the selection start is before or after the last line in the JTextArea, and to execute the commands when the enter key is pressed.

Hope this helps for now.
(I may come back and edit this later, make it less ugly, etc.)